# How to setup EMR cluster which supports Impala?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-emr, impala, apache-kudu

One of the aws document declares that impala is supported in EMR cluster. But i cant see impala option while creating EMR cluster. How can i get EMR cluster with impala-shell installed in it?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While creating the cluster use advanced options which will let you select the services you want in your cluster

Comment: Thanks for answer. but Impala is not listed in advanced options.

Comment: You also must be using an AMI and Amazon distribution of Hadoop 2.x (AMI 3.0.2 or later). It is not available after 4.x so you need to use older version https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=205230

Comment: Hey Thanks @Shubham Jain , it solved my problem.. i was using latest EMR version, thats why impala was not available.